# Vaadin MenuItem.setStyleName won't work

Tags: css, vaadin, vaadin7

I try to change the color of the items after this one is selected in vaadin. but no menuItems is selected when I click of an items.

```
   MenuBar.MenuItem previous = null;

    void createMenuBar(){

        menuBar = new MenuBar();
        menuBar.addItem("First Item", menuItem -> {
            if (previous != null)
                previous.setStyleName(null);
                menuItem.setStyleName("selected");
                previous = menuItem;
                someActions();
        });
        menuBar.addItem("Second Item", menuItem -> {
            // same action 
    });
```

Here a part of my style.css

```
.v-menubar-user-menu .v-menubar-menuitem-selected {
    color: #e2f6e7;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.v-menubar-user-menu .v-menubar-menuitem-selected:hover {
    color: #e2f6e7;
}
```

Comment: When you inspect the styles of the menu item you set with "selected" style, is it present? Maybe your CSS does not select the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

Edit!

I assumed menu item was a component, which it is not.

Try this:

```
MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();

menuBar.addItem("test",item -> {
    for(MenuBar.MenuItem m : menuBar.getItems())
        m.setStyleName("");
    item.setStyleName("selected");
});
```

Alternatively you could use the native vaadin style names in your css:

```
v-menubar-menuitem-selected
```

Comment: menuBar doesn't have a children member. I can only get a list of MenuItems

Comment: sorry I assumed menuItem was some component, but it is not. Changed the answer